# Ayuda con cálculo XSL

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

tengo un pequeño problema y no alcanzo a entender xsl.
El caso es que tengo un xml con una tienda, que contiene productos y por otro lado, clientes, los cuales tienen nombre, apellidos, 4 tipos de numero de telefono, y la lista de la compra.

Lo que es ordenar los clientes, con sus nombres y todo eso lo tengo listo.

Lo que me falta es el poder calcular el subtotal de cada producto que compran (cantidad * precioProducto)

La cantidad está en la lista de la compra y el precioProducto está en la lista de productos.

Mejor dejo el codigo que tengo puesto:

> ACLARACIÓN: El contenido completo del XML esta generado por un script
>   java, tanto nombres como numeros tanto las facturas son ficticias.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="factures.xsl"?>
<tenda>
    <productes>
        <producte preuUnitat='2.0'>Vi blanc botella 1L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='5.0'>Vi blanc botella 2L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='7.0'>Vi blanc garrafa 3L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='10.0'>Vi blanc garrafa 5L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='12.0'>Vi negre botella 1L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='15.0'>Vi negre botella 2L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='20.0'>Vi negre garrafa 3L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='25.0'>Vi negre garrafa 5L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='30.0'>Vi rosat botella 1L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='50.0'>Vi rosat botella 2L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='60.0'>Vi rosat garrafa 3L</producte>
        <producte preuUnitat='70.0'>Vi rosat garrafa 5L</producte>
    </productes>
    <factures>
        <factura numero="1">
            <client>
                <nom>Maria Josefa</nom>
                <cognoms>Crespo Soto</cognoms>
                <telefons>
                    <mobil tipus="feina">701 194 296</mobil>
            </telefons>
            </client>
            <compra>
                <producte id='n2'>9</producte>
                <producte id='n3'>3</producte>
                <producte id='r1'>4</producte>
                <producte id='r2'>1</producte>
                <producte id='r3'>2</producte>
            </compra>
        </factura>
        <factura numero="2">
            <client>
                <nom>Manuela</nom>
                <cognoms>Lara Rico</cognoms>
                <telefons>
                    <mobil tipus="privat">665 852 593</mobil>
                    <fixe tipus="privat">943 213 214</fixe>
                    <fixe tipus="feina">979 427 658</fixe>
            </telefons>
            </client>
            <compra>
                <producte id='b1'>10</producte>
                <producte id='b2'>6</producte>
                <producte id='b3'>2</producte>
                <producte id='b5'>9</producte>
                <producte id='r3'>7</producte>
            </compra>
        </factura>
        <factura numero="3">
            <client>
                <nom>Emilio</nom>
                <cognoms>Santos</cognoms>
                <telefons>
                    <mobil tipus="privat">725 215 087</mobil>
                    <fixe tipus="privat">810 696 902</fixe>
            </telefons>
            </client>
            <compra>
                <producte id='b2'>1</producte>
                <producte id='b3'>3</producte>
                <producte id='n2'>9</producte>
                <producte id='n3'>4</producte>
                <producte id='r1'>1</producte>
                <producte id='r2'>1</producte>
            </compra>
        </factura>
    </factures>
</tenda>
```

Y el XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="compra">
        <div class="listaCompra">
            <xsl:for-each select="producte">
                <div class="idProd"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></div>
                <div class="nomProd"><xsl:value-of select="/tenda/productes/producte/."/></div>
                <div class="cantProd"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
                <div class="precProd"><xsl:value-of select=". * $temp"/></div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
            <xsl:for-each select="/tenda/productes/producte">
                <xsl:value-of select="@preuUnitat"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Dejo tambien una captura de lo que tengo:

[image: Imagen de como quedaría la cosa]

EDIT:
Ya lo solucioné todo. con un xsl:key pude hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el siguiente XPath:

```
<span>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(tenda/productes/producte/@preuUnitat)"/>
</span>
```

Bueno ese Xpath suma y este multiplica la suma por la cantidad:

```
<span>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(tenda/productes/producte/@preuUnitat)*count(tenda/productes/producte/@preuUnitat)"/>
</span>
```

Puedes jugar con eso y revisar [funciones numericas en XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#numeric-functions)

Comment: Buenas Abrahamhs, He probado lo que me has comentado, pero creo que me expliqué mal. Con lo me has puesto, lo primero, me da la suma del precio unitario de la lista productos. (306)
Debo multiplicar el precioUnidad de la lista productos por la cantidad de la lista de la compra mostrado en la imagen como celda azulada.

Comment: Lo que me acabo de dar cuenta de un fallo enorme, es que siempre sale el mismo nombre del producto, estoy trabajando para repararlo.

Comment: `precioUnidad` no existe en el xml por eso te puse `Puedes jugar con eso` no se de donde sacar ese dato.